# Running Logger.log onEdit? Was trying to check data validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was trying to see if onEdit would activate if an incorrect entry was made to a cell that had data validation set to reject input on invalid data.  I could not get it to work using onEdit, so amended the function to myonEdit and set up the notification on the sheet.  I got the same result.

Have I done something wrong with this?

```
function myonEdit() {
    var mycell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
    Logger.log('The cell edited was ' & mycell)
}
```

Execution transcript was:

```
[16-04-21 05:09:33:624 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:625 PDT] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:625 PDT] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:625 PDT] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:625 PDT] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:626 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:714 PDT] Starting execution
[16-04-21 05:09:33:719 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:720 PDT] Spreadsheet.getActiveCell() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:720 PDT] Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:722 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[16-04-21 05:09:33:724 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.003 seconds total runtime]
```

But the log contained

```
[16-04-21 05:09:33:721 PDT] 0.0
```

Have I done this properly?  Is it not possible to use the Logger with simple triggers?  And will an onEdit event be activated by an incorrect entry into a validated cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'&' is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) in javascript. Use '+' sign to concatinate strings:

```
Logger.log('The cell edited was ' + mycell)
```

Comment: Many thanks for that Max.  Logger logging and I don't need to worry about data validation interfering with the onEdit event.  Cheers!